# Why this PHP function "forgets" parameters?

Tags: php

I've fount this implementation of a function to convert an array to a URL. It seems correct and, in fact, it works pretty well in many cases, except when I pass an array value with a 0 value. This is the function:

```
function strtourl($arr, $entity = true, $prefix = '') {
    $params = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
        if ($v) {
            $params[] = is_array($v) ? strtourl($v, $entity, $prefix ? $prefix.'['.$k.']' : $k) :
                        sprintf($prefix ? $prefix.'[%s]' : '%s', urlencode($k)).'='.urlencode($v);
        }
    return implode($entity ? '&amp;' : '&', $params);
}
```

This is an example I'm using:

```
$array = array(
    'type' => 0,
    'content' => array(
        'msg_id'    => 'XSS120',
        'source'    => 0,
        'dest'      => 4,
        'type'      => 0,
        'msg'       => 'message'
    )
);
```

It returns this string:

```
content[msg_id]=XSS120&content[dest]=4&content[msg]=message
```

instead of this:

```
type=0&content[msg_id]=XSS120&content[source]=0&content[dest]=4&content[type]=0&content[msg]=message
```

What's happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if ($v) {` is your problem. 0 evaluates to false, so it's being skipped.

I suggest removing that `if`, it's unneeded.

Comment: Or changing it to:

if (!is_null($v)) {

Answer (score 3):

There's already a native PHP function for this if you want to use it:

> #### http_build_query
>
> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed)
> array provided.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Demo: http://codepad.org/EtqXSGrH

Comment: Yep, no need to duplicate existing functionality. Interesting that OP's function is called `strtourl` but accepts arrays...

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, zero evaluates as False, so when you check `if ($v) {`, that evaluates as false and will not execute the code block just below it.

you could change that to

```
if (!empty($v) || $v == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the value `0` of `source` and `type` in your `$array`.